# how to simulate a cloud environment using java

Tags: java, cloud, environment, simulate

I would like to simulate a cloud computing environment for testing purpose. I would prefer to develop this environment using java.
I am not sure where to start and how to start as I have never done simulation earlier on. I am aware of cloudsim but I would rather try to simulate the environment programmatically.

Any ideas or suggestions please?

Comment: what do you mean by simulate cloud computing environment?

Comment: @sethu i have to do some analysis about data reliability in a cloud. Since I do not have the resources to create an actual cloud. I am trying to simulate a cloud . On fly change the number of servers in the cloud depending on the requirements etc.

Comment: i dont think its feasible to create such a thing. Why not try amazon its cheap and you can turn the instances on just for the period of the testing and shut it down. Its very cheap then and you can get all your testing done. Why try reinventing the wheel.. and trust me this is a very big wheel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Engine Java SDK enables you to debug your code locally on your computer. Above all it gives you the ability to simulate the consistency model.
From their SDK:

> You can configure the local datastore to simulate the consistency model of the High Replication Datastore. This will give you a good idea how an application configured to use the High Replication Datastore will operate in production.

For more information please go over http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver.html

Answer (score 0):

Requirements are not very clear. But I think that you can modify some open source peer to peer networking api for the purpose as you can enable file redundancy etc in it. Then you can run multiple instances of the p2p clients to simulate servers in the cloud.